# Deploy a Laravel 5 application

Tags: laravel, web, deployment

I wrote a Laravel 5 application (I am totally new to Laravel, and developed the application on my local computer (using xampp as web server). Now, I need to deploy the application on the server. The IT dept gave me the username/password. I used putty and winscp to login. 
When I logged-in by using Winscp, I saw a shortcut of the "domain name". When I click on the shortcut, it display as below:
/var/www/client/client1/web1
--webdav
--web
--tmp
--ssl
--private
--log
--home
--cgi-bin
--backup
I have no idea about the structure of the web. What should I do to deploy the Laravel application?
It might be a stupid question, but I really need your help.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: do you have the ability to change doc root?

Comment: Just by copying the content won't do. The IT dept has to copy/adapt the web server configuration (http.conf in Apache) from your local to the server.

Comment: @Achraf Khouadja: I have no idea. What should I do to check? And if I can, what I will do? If possible, can you give me a link or an instruction to help me to do that?

Comment: @Amarnasan: I don't have to do anything before, just copy the content to the server. Does it mean that this web server has not been configured yet? Is it easy to config? He is on vacation, and I need to deploy it urgent.

Comment: @Amarnasan: I would like to start with simple things by running a simple index.php. However, I don't know where to copy?

Comment: Why don't you just copy  an index.php file with "hello world" in the root (/web1), /web1/web, /web1/home directories and access the main page of the web in the server? Just to know if there is already a configuration set for your application

Comment: I did but it does not work. I think that the server was not configured but don't know where to start.